# A stronger result of the theorem, Action is primitive iff $G_x$ is maximal for all $x \in X$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I'm reading through Stephen Lovett's *Abstract Algebra* on group actions.

I understood the proof of Proposition 8.3.8, that if $G$ acts transitively on $X$, then the action is primitive iff $G_x$ is maximal for all $x \in X$.

But then, using the fact that $G_{gx}=gG_xg^{-1}$, Lovett claims that the Corollary is a stronger result:

[image]

I do not understand why this is a stronger result. I also do not understand parts of the proof, such as equation (8.5), and why it seems as though only one direction of the proof is given. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It’s “stronger” because you get the same conclusion for fewer hypotheses. The original theorem requires the maximality condition for *all* $x\in X$; the corollary only requires it for a *single* $x\in X$. Thus, weaker hypothesis but same conclusion, which is considered a “stronger” theorem.  As to the proof, the theorem guarantees that if it is primitive then $G_x$ is maximal for *all* $x\in X$, hence it is maximal for *one* $x\in X$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. One last question, though: It seems that we need to prove that if there is some $x \in X$ for which $G_x$ is maximal, then $G_y$ is maximal for all $y \in X$. But in the proof of the corollary, we start by assuming that $G_x$ is not maximal, and prove that $G_y$ is not maximal for all $y$. Why? Isn't that the opposite direction?

Comment: They are proving that there exists one which is not maximal if and only if none are maximal. That’s equivalent to proving that there is one that is maximal if and only if all of them are maximal.